# Kotlin - extension property setter for mutable subclass

Tags: kotlin, properties, extension-methods

Assume that I want to have a property for `List` and then extend this property with setter for `MutableList`. For example, I want to have a getter for last element in the list, and also a setter if the list is mutable. So I want the following:

```
val <T> List<T>.myLast
    get() = this.last()

var <T> MutableList<T>.myLast: T
    set(value) {
        this[this.size - 1] = value
    }
```

But this doesn't compile. Can this be achieved? The closest things I can do:

1. Declare another property:

   ```
   val <T> List<T>.myLast
       get() = this.last()

   var <T> MutableList<T>.myMutableLast: T
       get() = this.last()
       set(value) {
           this[this.size - 1] = value
       }
   ```

   I don't like this because I want to have the same name.
2. Create getter and setter explicitly:

   ```
   fun<T> List<T>.getMyLast() = this.last()

   fun<T> MutableList<T>.setMyLast(value : T) {
       this[this.size - 1] = value
   }
   ```

   I don't like it because it doesn't have property syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a getter to the second property which calls the first one:

```
val <T> List<T>.myLast
    get() = this.last()

var <T> MutableList<T>.myLast: T
    @JvmName("someName")
    get() = (this as List<T>).myLast
    set(value) {
        this[this.size - 1] = value
    }
```

In this case you could equally do `get() = this.last()`, but this way changing the first definition automatically affects the second one.

It'll get resolved like method overloading does, so e.g.

```
val x: List<String> = mutableListOf("")
val y: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
x.myLast // calls List<T>.myLast.get()
y.myLast // calls MutableList<T>.myLast.get()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you mean that I first declare `val <T> List<T>.myLast
    get() = this.last()` and then what you have written? Then I get `"Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature ...:
    fun List<T>.<get-myLast>(): ...
    fun MutableList<T>.<get-myLast>(): ..."`.

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked that this will happen in this specific case because `List` and `MutableList` are mapped to the same type. So you need a `@JvmName` annotation on one of the getters.